# Error with chinese encoding with php

Tags: php, encoding

I have a file that contain Chinese character Like this :

```
合作伙伴
```

problem and result looks like this :

```
ºÏ×÷»ï°é£º
```

Even if I try to print the content in the browser , I get the same encoding problem.

I m sure it's an encoding problem but I can't fix it.

Comment: Do you have a meta tag showing UTF-8 encoding in your HTML? `echo '<meta charset="utf-8">合作伙伴';` otherwise the browser won't know how to display it correctly.

Comment: There is a tag <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=gb2312"/> but My main problem is that when I try to paste a part of the text in a file with php, the Chinese character looks like ºÏ×÷»ï°é£º

Comment: I just remarked that if I remove <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=gb2312"/> from the html file, the text look like ºÏ×÷»ï°é£º even if it looks ok if I open it with file editor.
My problem Is that I can't read a part of the html file and put the it in another file with keeping the correct encoding.

Comment: You need to use a utf-8 compatible editor, like [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/3), are you using notepad or similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chinese character encoding is usually `gb2312`.

try to `gb2312` convert to `utf-8`

`$str = iconv('gb2312', 'utf-8', $str);`

make sure your file is utf-8 encoding.

`Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8`

Answer (score 0):

Convert character encoding to utf-8 and use that only:

```
$string = iconv('gb2312', 'utf-8', $string);
```